# Adobe acrobat DC and its toolbar in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on application and using Firefox, in that i have PDF in on of the page. and i have below questions on that,

1. PDF is not getting opened in web page itself instead it is asking with link 'Tap here to activate plugin' (inside place where pdf will open). Once i click on that it will get open. But through selenium code i am not able to click on that(not able to identify element). i tried to use setPreference but Adobe Acrobat is not getting activated.
2. IF the PDF opens then i have to mouse over on that and perform action like print, zoom-in and zoom-out on Adobe Acrobat DC toolbar and validate functionality.

Could you please help me to resolve these two issues screen shots are attached.

Thanks

Comment: First setup manualy new Firefox profile with the plugin and verify everything is fine when proceeding manualy. Second load selenium with the dedicated Firefox profile.